# Open file chooser from another class

Tags: java, dialog, jfilechooser

I have a seperate class that extends SwingWorker, I want it to open a file in background and when done it will set the text of a component in the Main class.

Isn't it possible to open the filechooser somehow like this? `fc.showOpenDialog(Main);` Because this gives me errors when building.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument passed to `showOpenDialog` should be the parent component for the dialog. So if your Main class extends Component, you can pass an instance of that class to `showOpenDialog`. You cannot simply pass a class name.